# Refactoring: Self invoking function instead of Extract method ?

Tags: refactoring

I'm reading the 'Refactoring' book, and i'm at the "Extract method" technique:

Original code:

```
void printOwing() {
  printBanner();

  //print details
  System.out.println ("name:  " + _name);
  System.out.println ("amount " + getOutstanding());
}
```

Refactored code with "Extract method" technique:

```
void printOwing() {
  printBanner();
  printDetails(getOutstanding());
}

void printDetails (double outstanding) {
  System.out.println ("name:  " + _name);
  System.out.println ("amount " + outstanding);
}
```

What if instead I would write an immediately invoked function, which would have the benefit of clearly isolating and name labeling the part of code I would have extracted ? Within the IDE, I could collapse this method and have the benefit of clearly see the flow without extracted method in some other place:

```
 void printOwing() {
      printBanner();

   void printDetails (double outstanding) { // collapsed in the ide
      System.out.println ("name:  " + _name);
      System.out.println ("amount " + getOutstanding());
     }() // self invokation
    }
```

Isn't this better than the "Extraction method" ? From your experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's motivates method extraction here?

In [this article with your exact example](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method) it says:

*"The more lines found in a method, the harder it is to figure out what the method does. This is the main reason for this refactoring."*

As well as providing a meaningful name for a chunk of code, which your alternative solution also does, actually moving the code out of the original method keeps methods small and readable.

Edit: As it has been pointed out it makes it easier to extract into classes and reuse. It also eliminates complex sharing of variables via closures.

Comment: indeed, the goal is to move out code and reduce method size, good point.

Comment: @Benj Also, I can't quite articulate this, but I think immediately invoked methods read poorly and their non-standardness (imo, but I don't develop in your language) suggest there's some special circumstance when there in fact isn't.

Comment: Also "Besides eliminating rough edges in your code, extracting methods is also a step in many other refactoring approaches". You can't e.g. extract a class if the related methods you could move out are buried somewhere, and potentially rely on closures.

Answer (score 2):

An additional benefit beyond naming a chunk of code through extraction is to make it available for reuse. An immediately invoked function cannot be called from a different context whereas a separate function/method can be made available to code elsewhere.